# Bow/Bower example in java oracle tutorial with lock object

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking, reentrantlock

In the java docs example, the `lock.unlock()` method is used twice, once in impendingBow() method and bow() method. My question is, shouldn't `lock.unlock()` method in `impendingBow()` method do the trick, why use it again in `bow()` method? The code below is a snippet from java docs :

```
public class Safelock {
static class Friend {
    private final String name;
    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public Friend(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public boolean impendingBow(Friend bower) {
        Boolean myLock = false;
        Boolean yourLock = false;
        try {
            myLock = lock.tryLock();
            yourLock = bower.lock.tryLock();
        } finally {
            if (! (myLock && yourLock)) {
                if (myLock) {
                    lock.unlock();
                }
                if (yourLock) {
                    bower.lock.unlock();
                }
            }
        }
        return myLock && yourLock;
    }

    public void bow(Friend bower) {
        if (impendingBow(bower)) {
            try {
                System.out.format("%s: %s has"
                    + " bowed to me!%n", 
                    this.name, bower.getName());
                bower.bowBack(this);
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
                bower.lock.unlock();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.format("%s: %s started"
                + " to bow to me, but saw that"
                + " I was already bowing to"
                + " him.%n",
                this.name, bower.getName());
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Method `impendingBow` calls `lock.unlock()` only when one of `tryLock()` call has been failed (note on `if (! (myLock && yourLock))` check). In that case the method returns *false*. `bow` method calls `lock.unlock()` only after `impendingBow()` call returns *true*. No problems there.

Comment: Just want to say that it's a very strange complicated example that more does confuse that demonstrates how the locks can work.... IMHO

Answer (score 0):

> shouldn't `lock.unlock()` method in `impendingBow()` method do the trick, why use it again in `bow()` method?

In `impendingBow`, when both lock attempts were successful, then the `lock.unlock()` will not be reached. The method returns `true`, leaving both locks in locked state. See the conditional statement before the unlock calls. In this case (both locks succeeded), `bow()` must unlock the locks.